# Magento redirects from checkout back to card - please help

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, error, redirect

I've got a problem with my **magento** **checkout**. after clicking on "checkout as a guest" OR "signup for checkout" magento redirects permanently (!) from the checkout back to the card. there's no chance to walk through the checkout.

here's the log from the exception.log
("Ungültiger Blocktyp" means "invalid blocktype"):

```
    2017-12-06T20:13:32+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Ungültiger Blocktyp: Mage_Facebook_Block_List' in /home/shopchec/public_html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/shopchec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Ung\xC3\xBCltiger Blo...')
#1 /home/shopchec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('facebook/list', Array)
#2 /home/shopchec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('facebook/list', 'facebook.list.d...')
#3 /home/shopchec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('facebook/list', 'facebook.list.d...')
#4 /home/shopchec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/shopchec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /home/shopchec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /home/shopchec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /home/shopchec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(194): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
#9 /home/shopchec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_CartController->indexAction()
#10 /home/shopchec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#11 /home/shopchec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /home/shopchec/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /home/shopchec/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /home/shopchec/public_html/index.php(84): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of your layout files contains a block with type `facebook/list` that does not exist.
Look in the files for something like `type="facebook/list"` and remove the full xml node that contains it.

Comment: thank you marius for your fast answer... in which file i have to search for that?

Comment: I have no idea. this is not a standard core block. search in all the files

Comment: i went to CMS -> Pages -> homepage and then to Layout/Layout Update XML and searched for anything like "facebook", but there's nothing like that - what can i do? where can i find the incorrect code to delete it? do you mean all the files which are namend in the exception.log?

Comment: all the xml files in your code.

Comment: sorry, where can i find it? i think i don't know the right place where i have to search... in the backend or in files/folder?

Comment: files . I thought I made that clear